# Forms for nested ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have a model that I can update through the form

```
instance.update(some_relations: [ {id: 1, some_other_relation_id: 26}])
```

This works great. The some_relation with id 1's some_other_relation is updated to point to 26.

However I have no idea how to create the form for this. I'd be looking for the html to look like

```
   .... name=model[some_relation][][id] type="hidden"
   .... name=model[some_relation][][some_other_relation_id]
```

But I am unsure on how to do that using the in-built form helpers (which I would prefer over hard-coding it).

Comment: Read about `accepts_nested_attributes_for`: http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/

Comment: Accepts_nested_attributes_for is a model property, my model works great. (It already has accepts_nested_attributes for some_relation) I can do what I want through rails c perfectly. My question is how to build a form for it nicely.

As you can see in my html I'm wanting to avoid using some_relation_attributes aswell.

Comment: you are looking for [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) this will handle the associations in the form.

Comment: What have you tried so far, as for the form building goes? Share some form relevant code that you have tried.